# Why are hydrogen ions always associated with another molecule?

Tags: ions, hydrogen

I was reading N.C.E.R.T. class XI part 2 book and chapter Hydrogen,when I came across this statement:

> Loss of the electron from hydrogen atom
>   results in nucleus ($\ce{H+}$) of ~1.510–3 pm size.
>   This is extremely small as compared to normal
>   atomic and ionic sizes of 50 to 200pm. As a
>   consequence, H+ does not exist freely and is
>   always associated with other atoms or
>   molecules.

So a question arose in my mind that why it is a consequence of small size of hydrogen nucleus that $\ce{H+}$ does not exist freely and is always associated with other atoms and molecules?

Comment: Think of what you are referring to when you say H+ (or a hydrogen ion)

Comment: i am referring to  a proton.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22193/is-it-possible-for-hydrogen-to-lose-its-electron

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way I understand it is (and my understanding is by no means perfect, or complete), as you pointed out correctly: a hydrogen ion is in fact a proton. The proton is a "bare charge" and as you rightly said, "tiny". a
This makes it extremely reactive (in a sense), and thus in a chemical system of any sort would immediately seek out and associate with the electron clouds of a surrounding molecule.

For instance, in an aqueous solution it forms $\ce{H_3O+}$ (hydronium ion, which are further solvated by water molecules and form a manner of aggregates).

An extremely interesting way of looking at it was pointed out in the comments (just putting it here, so no one misses it)

> An interesting way to thinking about the reactivity of a bare proton is to calculate its charge density and compare with other monocations, such as Li+. This will make it clear why free protons will abstract electrons from just about anything. –  Nicolau Saker Neto

Do note (as far as I know, someone might correct me if I am wrong) free protons are fairly stable (by free I mean not bound to electrons or other nucleons) and usually don't decay into other particles. They exist in several naturally occurring situations, high energy plasmas come to mind.

Comment: Free protons are extremely if not indefinitely stable to nuclear decay, with a half-life of at least about $10^{35}$ years. An interesting way to thinking about the reactivity of a bare proton is to calculate its *charge density* and compare with other monocations, such as $\ce{Li+}$. This will make it clear why free protons will abstract electrons from just about anything.

Comment: Nicolau, thank you for your comment, and I do prefer your way of looking at the problem, hence I have edited and added it to my answer. hope you don't mind

Comment: Sure, no problem at all. I actually wound up discussing it a long time ago, in [this answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/9934/1499).