# can protons or H+ appear as stable gas?

Tags: hydrogen

Can H+ appear as stable gas or they react to form H2? Can H+ appear as stable gas or they react to form H2? Can H+ appear as stable gas or they react to form H2? Can H+ appear as stable gas or they react to form H2? thanks!

Comment: And can you tell me why you wrote 3 times the same sentence?

Comment: There's a reason that the minimum character requirement is in place.  It usually takes *at least* that much text to set up the background and explain what you have tried.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46882/do-bare-protons-exist-even-transiently-in-aqueous-solution http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32558/why-are-hydrogen-ions-always-associated-with-another-molecule

Comment: @Mithoron it says 'Adding a bare proton to a molecule is a real event in the gas phase' so is it possible to produce a proton beam as we do easily with electron beams? even in vacuum, I don't care

Comment: Off course you can make proton beam, it's even used for therapy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_therapy but it's by no means a gas, not even plasma, but separated particles. In the future you need to word your questions properly and say exactly what you're asking. Also this is rather physics than chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

A bare naked proton is one of the most reactive species known.  Finding them in the gas phase is unlikely in terrestrial conditions.  Additionally, there are some charge balance issues

However, hydrogen plasma is known to be abundant in the universe, forming the primary composition of most stars.  This would be H+ ions swimming in a sea of electrons.  It requires intense energy to keep this state, and without an input of heat the plasma will condense to hydrogen atoms, which will then form hydrogen gas.

Comment: though H+ are very common in liquids and cells, yet you say it's impossible to ionize H+ gas?

Comment: it's easy to produce a beam of electrons, isn't it that easy to produce a beam of protons?

Comment: Free H+ are not common.  Electrostaticly interacting H+ (such as with a solvent) are very common.